# How to get Scala plugin and AJDT to be installed in same Eclipse

Tags: scala, eclipse-3.5, ajdt

I get an error when trying to install both AJDT and Scala 2.7.5 plugin into Eclipse 3.5.

I remember seeing a message at one point that there was a known problem with the two being installed, and the solution was to install a pre-release version of Scala plugin, from May I believe, then install AJDT.

But, I don't remember which version and I can't find a link to download the older pre-release version.

So, I am wondering if someone knows how I can get both installed.

Thank you.

---

Edit:
I tried it just now and got this error, so AJDT 1.7.0 won't work. :(

```
    Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Scala Eclipse Plugin 2.7.5.final (ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.feature.group 2.7.5.final)
  Software being installed: AspectJ Development Tools 2.0.0.e35x-20090624-1600 (org.eclipse.ajdt.feature.group 2.0.0.e35x-20090624-1600)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    JDT Weaving 2.0.0.e35x-20090624-1600 (org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt 2.0.0.e35x-20090624-1600)
    JDT Weaving 1.6.4.20090313172428 (org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt 1.6.4.20090313172428)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Scala Eclipse Plugin 2.7.5.final (ch.epfl.lamp.sdt.feature.group 2.7.5.final)
    To: org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt [1.6.4.20090313172428]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: AspectJ Development Tools 2.0.0.e35x-20090624-1600 (org.eclipse.ajdt.feature.group 2.0.0.e35x-20090624-1600)
    To: org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt [2.0.0.e35x-20090624-1600]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2560),

> 2.7.5.final is compatible with AJDT 1.7.0 on Eclipse 3.5.

If you have [AJDT (AspectJ Development Tools) 2.0.x](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/), could you try to downgrade to 1.7.0 as [suggested in this thread](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/2807)?

As the OP ([James Black](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67566/james-black)) himself details in the comments, both AJDT versions are actually 2.0!

From "[AJDT 2.0.0 - New and Noteworthy](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/whatsnew200/)":

> - Release for AJDT targeting Eclipse 3.5: 2.0.0_e35x2009XXXXXX
> - Release for AJDT targeting Eclipse 3.4:   2.0.0_e34x2009XXXXXX
>
> So this means that **AJDT 1.6.5 has been renamed AJDT 2.0.0_e34x and AJDT 1.7.0 has been renamed AJDT 2.0.0_e35x**.
>   Although this is potentially confusing in the short term, we believe in the long term, this will be more informative and users will be able to read the version and immediately know which Eclipse version it targets and also what feature level it contains.

---

To complete this answer with the OP's feedback:

- [AJDT update site](http://eclipse.ialto.org/tools/ajdt/35/dev/update/)
- "[Eclipse Galileo, AJDT, Scala Eclipse plugin 2.7.5](http://www.nabble.com/Eclipse-Galileo,-AJDT,-Scala-Eclipse-plugin-2.7.5-td24357850.html)"

> > Hmm ... if you can live with one of the 1.7.0 AJDT builds you should be OK.
> >     Cheers, Miles
>
> Thanks for the tip - it works!
>   I used [`ajdt_1.7.0.20090513085548_archive.zip`](http://eclipse.ialto.org/tools/ajdt/35/dev/update/ajdt_1.7.0.20090513085548_archive.zip) from the AJDT downloads.
>   cheers Porter

Comment: I tried 1.7.0, which is also 2.0 as explained here:
So this means that AJDT 1.6.5 has been renamed AJDT 2.0.0_e34x and AJDT 1.7.0 has been renamed AJDT 2.0.0_e35x.
http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/whatsnew200/
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the message I couldn't find, looking for AJDT 1.7 was the help I needed:
http://www.nabble.com/Eclipse-Galileo,-AJDT,-Scala-Eclipse-plugin-2.7.5-td24357850.html

You can get the file from:
http://eclipse.ialto.org/tools/ajdt/35/dev/update/

I unzipped this zip file into the Eclipse directory, then installed Scala 1.7.5.

Answer (score 0):

I have AJDT 2.0.0 installed, and when trying to install Scala 2.7.5.final get this message:

```
Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
  JDT Weaving 2.0.0.e35x-20090624-1600 (org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt 2.0.0.e35x-20090624-1600)
  JDT Weaving 1.6.4.20090313172428 (org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt 1.6.4.20090313172428)
```

This is because the Scala plugin requires 1.6.4. If you downgrade to that version of AJDT you may be ok.